# NiFI / How to insert many JSON flowfiles into MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, json, csv, apache-nifi

So I'm using NiFI to convert a CSV file into JSON format and then I convert it to SQL using ConvertJsonToSQL processor. The problem is when I try to insert my file into my database using PutSQL, nothing happens. The file contains 510k lines, I tried with only 2 lines and it worked, but not with the original size.

This is what NiFi is showing when I try to insert :

[image]

After that, my database is still empty. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Maybe you exceed max_packet_size? check MySQL Error Log.

Comment: I'm using DBeaver I noticed nothing while I was executing